# how to set up checkbox value while creating a node

Tags: nodes

Here is my code. I have a problem with while creating node. There are three checkboxes which user have to select; only the last checkbox of data (black color) is saved for node.

What is wrong with my code?

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'product';
node_object_prepare($node);

$node->title    = $title;
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

$node->field_operator['und']['0']['tid'] = 135;// white color
$node->field_operator['und']['0']['tid'] = 136;// blue color
$node->field_operator['und']['0']['tid'] = 162;// black color

node_save($node);
```

Comment: You are assigning to `$node->field_operator['und']['0']['tid']` three different values, which means PHP will keep the last value. It is like executing `$i = 10; $i = 20; $i = 80;` and wonder why `$i` is equal to 80.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the field can accept multiple values, the code should be similar to the following one.

```
    $node->field_operator['und'][0]['tid'] = 135;
    $node->field_operator['und'][1]['tid'] = 136;
    $node->field_operator['und'][2]['tid'] = 162;
```